# Java: JFrame Layout for Only Drawing?

Tags: java, swing, layout, jframe

I'm wanting to draw my components on a JFrame based on coordinates. I don't want a layout to rearrange the components. My project isn't a GUI, it's a game where the images being drawn don't need to be laid out into a UI pattern.

Is there a layout (or a layout of null) that allows you to draw components onto the JFrame without them being rearranged?

Comment: Why are you using components and not using a custom painting approach which would give you greater control over all the aspects you need? Take a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and 
[Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more deatils

Comment: Swing components are designed to work with the aid of layout managers, removing it (the layout manager) increases your work load by an order of magnitude and shouldn't be done lightly and without good cause.  A better idea would be to use a custom painting approach, which would give you the control over the positioning of the entities, but without the issues involved in trying to manage the "layout" of your components manually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The soulution I was looking for was to have my Game class inherit from JFrame and then draw everything in JFrame's paint method.

```
public class Game extends JFrame
{
...
    public void paint (Graphics g){
        //Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        board.paintComponent(g);
        board.getPieceAt(0,0).paintComponent(g);
    }
...
}
```